# RFC 2822 email parsing

Tags: email

Is there a function somewhere in emacs already to parse RFC
2822-formatted email addresses? I don't particularly care for the
obsolete parts, but would like to be able to parse things like `"John
Smith" <john.smith@example.com>` into `("John Smith"
. "john.smith@example.com")`. I've gotten the following regex working,
but I figured gnus or someone must have done this properly already.

```
(defconst fov-email-address-regex
  (let* ((cfws `(? (any space)))
         (atom `(any alpha digit "!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}'~-"))
         (quoted-pair `(: "\"" (* (or (not (any "\"\\")) (: "\\" nonl))) "\""))
         (display-name `(* (or ,cfws ,atom ,quoted-pair)))
         (addr-spec `(group-n 1 (: (+ (any alpha digit ".!#$%&'*+-/=?\^_`{|}~-"))
                                   "@"
                                   (+ (any alpha digit "-")) (+ (: "." (+ (any alpha digit "-")))))))
         (angle-addr `(: ,cfws "<" ,addr-spec ">" ))
         (name-addr `(: (? ,display-name) ,angle-addr))
         (mailbox `(or ,addr-spec ,name-addr))
         (mailbox-list `(: ,mailbox (* (: "," ,mailbox))))
         (group `(: ,display-name ":" (or ,cfws ,mailbox-list) ";" ,cfws))
         (address `(or ,mailbox ,group)))
    (rx-to-string `(: string-start ,address string-end) t))
  "Regex used to parse an RFC 2822 email address.")
```

Comment: Have a look at the aliases defined in Emacs sources under `lisp/mail/mail-parse.el`.

Comment: Excellent! `ietf-drums-parse-address` is what I needed. If you answer, I'll accept :)

Comment: Glad I could help ;).

Comment: @Felipe Note that it is preferred to use the alias `mail-header-parse-address` from `mail-parse` instead of its current value `ietf-drums-parse-address` from `ietf-drums`, as the former comprises a standard interface and the latter may become obsolete in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the aliases defined in Emacs sources under `lisp/mail/mail-parse.el`.